# Añadir dato a un gráfico treemap

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente Df

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '

      Var1                     Porcentaje
Variable1                         0.6
Variable2                         0.4
Variable3                         0.23
Variable4                         0.19
Variable5                         0.10
Variable6                         0.04
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Hago un gráfico tipo Treemap:

```
library(treemap)
treemap(my.data ,
        index="Var1",
        vSize="Porcentaje",
        type="index"
)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Se puede incluir en el gráfico el datos del porcertaje en cada cuadro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo más sencillo y tal vez lo único que se puede hacer, es crear una variable nueva con el formato deseado:

```
my.data$etiqueta <- paste0(my.data$Var1, ": ", my.data$Porcentaje*100, "%")

library(treemap)

treemap(my.data ,
        index="etiqueta",
        vSize="Porcentaje",
        type="index"
)
```

Comment: Añadirle el porcentaje en el nombre. Sencillo a la par que brillante.